# Make a Computer Vision Application use Custom Vision

Tags: azure, computer-vision, azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-custom-vision

I built a Computer Vision Application following the Microsoft tutorial here:

https://github.com/Microsoft/computerscience/blob/master/Labs/Azure%20Services/Azure%20Storage/Azure%20Storage%20and%20Cognitive%20Services%20(MVC).md#Exercise1

Now I want to use customvision.ai instead of the standard Computer Vision. I moved my customvision project to Azure and thought I just had to change Subscription Key and Vision Endpoint but it does not seem to work.

```
<add key="VisionEndpoint" value="CustomVisionEndpoint" />
<add key="SubscriptionKey" value="ValueOfCustomVisionKeyInAzure" />
```

When I use the Computer Vision Endpoint and Key everything works fine, but if I use Custom Vision I get an error message:

```
Operation returned an invalid status code &#39;NotFound&#39;
```

Anyone have any idea? Do I have to change additional values or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

On Azure Cognitive Services, [Custom Vision Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/) is different from [Computer Vision](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/). They have different architectures, different APIs and different endpoints for calling. Therefore, their SDKs can not be compatible for each other.

You can deeper understand them via their offical samples for [`CustomVision`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/tree/master/CustomVision) and [`ComputerVision`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-dotnet-sdk-samples/tree/master/samples/ComputerVision), even through their REST APIs in the `Reference` of [`Cognitive Services`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/).

[image]

Comment: You can add that there is a Nuget package for CustomVision which is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.CustomVision.Prediction for the prediction side. The OP should use this package instead of the one mentioned in its demo (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.ComputerVision)